# Java - Convert a Signed int into a Signed Byte Array and Back

Tags: java, arrays, type-conversion, bit-shift

I would like to convert a *signed* int into a *signed* byte[] array, and later convert it back into a signed int.

However, ByteBuffers (The usual int->buffer->byte[] array) are too slow for this case.

Can this be done using basic operations?

I've seem many attempts, but I haven't seen one that works in all cases. (Usually, they fail for negative numbers.)

I am working in Java, so it is not possible to use unsigned values, even in intermediate steps.

Comment: Not sure if it will be exactly what you want but have you considered using `BigInteger`? It pulls the sign out of the initial value and then generated a `byte[]` containing the byte data of the unsigned value.

Comment: I'm curious as to how you've determined that `ByteBuffer` is too slow. Have you done performance tests? If so, what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void writeInt(int val, byte[] data, int offset) {
    data[offset    ] = (byte)(val >>> 24);
    data[offset + 1] = (byte)(val >>> 16);
    data[offset + 2] = (byte)(val >>> 8);
    data[offset + 3] = (byte)val;
}

private int readInt(byte[] data, int offset) {
    return (data[offset] << 24)
            | ((data[offset + 1] & 0xFF) << 16)
            | ((data[offset + 2] & 0xFF) << 8)
            | (data[offset + 3] & 0xFF);
}
```